How can I airdrop Solana when running anchor locally?
If I want an airdrop on devnet, I can just do solana airdrop <amount> <address>. What if I have a local cluster running with anchor localnet though, how do I airdrop then?

Figured it out. When running anchor localnet, it outputs a bunch of info about the local run like so:
Ledger location: .anchor/test-ledger
Log: .anchor/test-ledger/validator.log
⠚ Initializing...                                                                                                                     Waiting for fees to stabilize 1...
Identity: 56A3NB4ycuiP5AUSsZhthQcwL2q2nZVBiBQZ4ctwu7Qx
Genesis Hash: Da253hbZF7BgKVaHLPgCr8LHMWcWX6sQVtPShUn9cyjg
Version: 1.18.8
Shred Version: 51696
Gossip Address: 127.0.0.1:1024
TPU Address: 127.0.0.1:1027
JSON RPC URL: http://127.0.0.1:8899
WebSocket PubSub URL: ws://127.0.0.1:8900

Just take the JSON RPC URL from here and configure the solana CLI with it by doing solana config set --url http://127.0.0.1:8899.
Then we can do solana airdrop <amount> <address> like normal.

You've got it. As a shortcut you can do solana config set --url localhost or even solana config set --url l. You can also just set the url per command to avoid changing the whole config, eg solana airdrop --url localhost 1000

Didn't know these existed too, thanks Callum!
